# Why am I getting unsolicited result codes continuously on using SIM900A?

Tags: at-command, gprs, sim900

I have connected SIM900A serially with my PC and given it power using an adapter of 5V. As soon as the module receives signal from the SIM Card, it continuously posts result codes CPIN,CREG,CGREG. 
This image shows the output I keep on receiving in a loop.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7fQI.png)

Any help is appreciated,thanks!

Comment: You said you have a 5v adapter, but how much current? Sound it's not enough and makes module restart continuously.

Comment: 2A is the current.